# How to execute the equivalent cmd with GenericContainer from test containers lib

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

What is the right way of executing the following docker command in GenericContainer

```
docker container run \
   --publish 9092:9082 \
   --detach \
   --name h2 \
   nemerosa/h2

@ClassRule
public static GenericContainer h2db =
            new GenericContainer("nemerosa/h2")
                    .withCommand("--publish 9092:9082", "--detach", "--name lm", "nemerosa/h2")
                    .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(Constants.TIMEOUT_DURATION));
```

I cannot assert if the following commands are equivalent ?

Comment: I guess this relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212879/is-there-a-way-to-pass-docker-flags-in-genericcontainer-from-test-containers/62377798#62377798 and can be closed