# Is there a way to pass docker flags in GenericContainer from test containers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

Is there a way to pass those flags from this command in GenericContainer object from test-containers lib ?

```
docker container run \
   --publish 9092:9082 \
   --detach \
   --name h2 \
   nemerosa/h2

@ClassRule
public static GenericContainer h2db =
            new GenericContainer("nemerosa/h2")
             .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(Constants.TIMEOUT_DURATION));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exposing ports, Testcontainers offers a method on the `GenericContainer`:

```
@ClassRule
public static GenericContainer h2db =
    new GenericContainer("nemerosa/h2")
      .withExposedPorts(9092)
      .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(Constants.TIMEOUT_DURATION));
```

The `--detach` should be redundant as Testcontainers starts all of its containers in the background and detached.